# Background Img made in div makes div transparent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a div to have it's own background image, but every time I add the image it makes the div transparent so the main back ground shows through.  I've scoured this site and others but to no avail.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="Mobile video game parties offering the ultimate gaming experience. All inside a top of the line mobile gaming trailer." />
<meta name="fb_admins_meta_tag" content="USER_ID"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="WeGotGamez| Mobile Video Game Party"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.wegotgamez.com/"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="WeGotGamez| Mobile Video Game Party"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Mobile video game parties offering the ultimate gaming experience. All inside a top of the line mobile gaming trailer."/>
<META NAME="robot" CONTENT="index,follow">
<META NAME="refresh" CONTENT="120">


<head>
<title> Mobile Video Game Party| WeGotGamez| Mobile Gaming, Sacramento </title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage3.css">
<style>
body 
{
background-image:url('drkdp.jpg');

}
</style>
</head>


<body>


<div id="container" style="width:1060px;">

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <img src="c:\users\wgg1\desktop\websitemaint\gallery\hdrimg.png" style="float: right; width: 500px; height: 150px; margin-right: -100px; margin-left: 15px;"/><a href="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\index.html"><img  src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\logo.png"         style="float: left;margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; width: 400px; height: 135px;"/></a><h3 style="float:right;">3201 Evergreen Ave Ste 360</br>West Sacramento, CA, 95691</br>(916)945-0837</br><a href=https://www.facebook.com/WEGOTGAMEZ><img src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\Icons\fb16x16.png"/></a><a href=https://twitter.com/wegotgamez><img src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\Icons\twt16x16.png"/></a><a href=http://instagram.com/wegotgamez><img src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\Icons\igrm16x16.png"/></a>
    </div>
    </br>
</div>


<div id='cssmenu' style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 150px; margin-bottom: 25px;">
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\equipment.html'><span>Equipment</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\mobilegamingtrailer.html'><span>Mobile Gaming Trailer</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\mobilegamingcube.html'><span>Portable Gaming Stations</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\retroarcade.html'><span>Retro Arcade's</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Party Packages</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Schedule An Event</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\tournaments.html'><span>Tournaments</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About US</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Game Library</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\gallery.html'><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>FAQ</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div class="photobanner">
        <img class="first" src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\052.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\008.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\019.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\026.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\033.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\041.jpg" alt="">

</div>

<div id="col1"><h4 style="text-align:left; margin-left:5px">Let<b> We Got Gamez</b> and our friendly game coaches bring the ultimate in gaming experiences to your next event.<br><br><font face="wingdings"> &#171; </font><font face="wingdings"> &#171; </font><font face="wingdings"> &#171; </font><br><br>  Whether it be a birthday party, block party, wedding, or even an office team building event, we've got you covered.<br><br><font face="wingdings"> &#171; </font><font face="wingdings"> &#171; </font><font face="wingdings"> &#171; </font><br><br>  With our unique trailer set up and our extensive game libraries, your event will be the one everyone will be talking about for weeks to come!</h4>
<h4 style="text-align:left; margin-left:5px"><font face="wingdings"> &#171; </font><font face="wingdings"> &#171; </font><font face="wingdings"> &#171; </font>
    </h4>


    <h4 style="text-align:left; margin-left:5px">Check out the competition and you will see that we offer the most advanced and savvy mobile gaming platforms anywhere.<br><br><font face="wingdings"> &#171; </font><font face="wingdings"> &#171; </font><font face="wingdings"> &#171; </font><br><br>  Our gaming trailer comes equipped with 8 individual gaming stations each boasting an XBOX 360, PS3, gaming chair, stereo headset, and 24" t.v screens.<br><br><font face="wingdings"> &#171; </font><font face="wingdings"> &#171; </font><font face="wingdings"> &#171; </font><br><br>  We conform to the most popular gaming tournament standards and regulations, giving you a professional feel for house tournaments.</h4>
    </div>
<div id="col2"><h4 style="text-align:center;margin-right:15px;margin-left:15px;margin-top:15px">Our Mobile Gaming Trailer brings the party right to your house !</h4>

<img src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\042.jpg" style="align:center;width:450px;height:250px;margin-top:5px;">
    </hr>
    <h4 style="text-align:center;margin-left:15px;margin-right:15px;">No crowding around a single bench to play. Get a truly immersive experience with our unique gaming stations.</h4>
    <br>
    <img src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\052.jpg" style="align:center;width:450px;height:250px;margin-bottom:15px">
    <h4 style="text-align:center;margin-left:15px;margin-right:15px;">Our portable game cubes fit anywhere , inside or outside your business or home !</h4>
    </div>
<div id="col3"><h4 style="text-align:center;">Affiliations:</h4>
    <br>
    <img src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\sponsorimg\astro.png" style="align:center;width:150px;height:100px;margin-bottom:15px">
    <br>
    <img src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\sponsorimg\avngr.png" style="align:center;width:150px;height:100px;margin-bottom:15px">
    <br>
    <img src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\sponsorimg\skulc.png" style="align:center;width:150px;height:100px;margin-bottom:15px">
    <br>
    <img src="C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\sponsorimg\sqdgrp.png" style="align:center;width:150px;height:100px;margin-bottom:15px">
    <br>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>




<div id='cssmenu1' style="margin-left: -25px; margin-right: 35px; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: -25px; display:inline-block; position:relative">
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\equipment.html'><span>Equipment</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\mobilegamingtrailer.html'><span>Mobile Gaming Trailer</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\mobilegamingcube.html'><span>Portable Gaming Stations</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\retroarcade.html'><span>Retro Arcade's</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Party Packages</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Schedule An Event</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\tournaments.html'><span>Tournaments</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About US</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#' target='_blank'><span>Game Library</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\gallery.html'><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>FAQ</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>
<p style="color:blue; margin-top:-5px">© 2013 by We Got Gamez, Custom Upfits, and Electrical Service Specialties</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>




 html {
    text-align: center;


}

body{
    margin-right: 40px ;
    margin-left: 70px;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 70 px;
    height: 100%;

}
h1 {
    color:#FBF2EF;
    font-family: 'times new roman';
}
h2{
    color:#fbf2ef;
}
h3
{
    color:#fbf2ef;
    font-family: 'times new roman'

}
hr {
    color: #f00;
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 1px;
}

p {
     font-color:'white';
}
button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  padding:5px;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
strong{
    font-weight:bold;
}
#col1
{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-image:url('C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\dpimg3.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border:double 7px #000000;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;


}

#col2
{
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border:double 7px #000000;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

#col3
{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border:double 7px #000000;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
#col4{
    position:center;
    width: 48%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border:double 7px #000000;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
div .body{
border:double 7px #000000;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}   
#footer {
    margin-top: 150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    min-width: 1200px;


}

#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;

}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  min-width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a {
  background: #646464 url(grad_dark.png) repeat-x left bottom;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #646464), color-stop(100%, #4a4a4a));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#646464', endColorstr='#4a4a4a', GradientType=0);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #222222, inset 0 10px 10px #222222;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #222222, inset 0 10px 10px #222222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #222222, inset 0 10px 10px #222222;
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a:hover {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #646464), color-stop(100%, #4a4a4a));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#646464', endColorstr='#4a4a4a', GradientType=0);
  filter: none;

}
#cssmenu > ul > li a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
  background: #4a4a4a url(grad_dark.png) repeat-x left top;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #8a8a8a), color-stop(50%, #707070), color-stop(51%, #626262), color-stop(100%, #787878));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8a8a8a', endColorstr='#787878', GradientType=0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
  border-top: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
  border-right: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
  line-height: 34px;
  padding: 0 35px;
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a:hover {
  background: #8a8a8a url(grad_dark.png) repeat-x left bottom;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #646464), color-stop(50%, #4a4a4a), color-stop(51%, #3b3b3b), color-stop(100%, #525252));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8a8a8a', endColorstr='#787878', GradientType=0);
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 36px;
  left: -1px;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;

  /* IE7 */

  *width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  border-top: 0 none;
  border-left: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 9px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.photobanner {
    height: 65px;
    width: 960px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    margin-right:100px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 105px;
}


.photobanner img {
     height: 85px;
     width: 150px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.photobanner img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.0);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
div.container {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%
}
#cssmenu1{
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
}
#cssmenu1 ul,
#cssmenu1 li,
#cssmenu1 span,
#cssmenu1 a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;

}
#cssmenu1:after,
#cssmenu1 ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu1 a {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  min-width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #333333;
}
#cssmenu1 ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu1 > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu1 > ul > li.active a {
  background: #646464 url(grad_dark.png) repeat-x left bottom;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #646464), color-stop(100%, #4a4a4a));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#646464', endColorstr='#4a4a4a', GradientType=0);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #222222, inset 0 10px 10px #222222;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #222222, inset 0 10px 10px #222222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #222222, inset 0 10px 10px #222222;
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu1 > ul > li.active a:hover {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #646464), color-stop(100%, #4a4a4a));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#646464', endColorstr='#4a4a4a', GradientType=0);
  filter: none;

}
#cssmenu1 > ul > li a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
  background: #4a4a4a url(grad_dark.png) repeat-x left top;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #8a8a8a), color-stop(50%, #707070), color-stop(51%, #626262), color-stop(100%, #787878));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #8a8a8a 0%, #707070 50%, #626262 51%, #787878 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8a8a8a', endColorstr='#787878', GradientType=0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
  border-top: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
  border-right: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
  line-height: 34px;
  padding: 0 35px;
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu1 > ul > li a:hover {
  background: #8a8a8a url(grad_dark.png) repeat-x left bottom;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #646464), color-stop(50%, #4a4a4a), color-stop(51%, #3b3b3b), color-stop(100%, #525252));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #646464 0%, #4a4a4a 50%, #3b3b3b 51%, #525252 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8a8a8a', endColorstr='#787878', GradientType=0);
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu1 > ul > li:first-child a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
}
#cssmenu1 > ul > li:last-child a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#cssmenu1 .has-sub:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu1 .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 100%;

  /* IE7 */

  *width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu1.has-sub ul li {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu1 .has-sub ul li a {
  border-top: 0 none;
  border-left: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 9px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please include only the relevant portions of your code in the question.

Comment: Are you talking about `div#col1`? Does the image exist: "C:\Users\WGG1\Desktop\WebsiteMaint\Gallery\dpimg3.jpg"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Michael's answer...

Assuming that you have a transparent image that is allowing the previous background to leak through, you'll need to define a background color on the new div.

But keep in mind that if you use the compound attribute that it will override all the background attributes defined before it.

So in this case, all you'll see is white:

```
div.your_div_class {
  background-image: url('your_image.png');
  background: #FFF;
}
```

But if you use the specific image and the color background attributes they're additive. So in this case you'll get the image with a white background:

```
div.your_div_class {
  background-image: url('your_image.png');
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use image with transparency it could happen.

Maybe some CSS like:

```
div.your_div_class{
    background: url('some_image.png') #fff;
}
```

would help.
Use color like `#fff`(white) in `background` to not make it transparent.

You could use `background-color: #fff;` separately too.

Comment: So i added a color to the css, and now only the color shows up, ive checked and checked on the url path, the image exists...sorry it is #col1 btw........i added it as 'background-color:' separately and it went back to being transparent

Comment: Maybe try to use relative path from your project folder. Like your project is in folder `C:\www\mc-project` and your image is in `C:\www\mc-project\img\your_image.jpg` then assuming your css is located in `C:\www\mc-project\css\style.css` use path `..\img\your_image.jpg`